# Advanced weight calculation with large dataset in Python

Tags: python, finance, stock

I am to calculate weights of a portfolio the rebalances monthly. In the pasted dataset PERMNO is a stock, and i need to calculate the cumulative weights for this portfolio, i.e. the weight increases with the stocks return.

The case is:
Each day the weight is calculated like: w1 = w0*(1+r0)/(sum(all w1 that day)) for each stock. In excel this is no problem, but I run into problems in python. As w0 the next day is w1 the past day. I try to not use loops, as the dateset is large, but any solution is appreciated.
The dataframe i am working on is like this:

[image]

This is how i want the calculation to be:
[image]

As you see in the second picture, the weight day 2 is the new weight of day 1. This is were the problem lies.

Thank you!!

Comment: Which is kind of interesting, as basically what you're trying to do is to multiply initial weights by accumulated products of returns, which quickly explodes in superfluous calculations without caching intermediates. `w_i = w0_i * itertools.accumulate(df.return_factors_i, operator.mul) / sum_i(w0_i * itertools.accumulate(df.return_factors_i, operator.mul)`. Might want to look into `functools.cache` for the calls. I know it's possible to create a body of functions working in concert to emulate the behavior wanted, but what is actually wrong with creating it in a loop?

Comment: Right now i trying to solve it with a loop as well, but run into certain problems. Do you have a loop solution?

Answer (score 0):

You name avoidance of a looping through your data as your main problem. In this case I would like to make you aware, that you can read your whole file line by line, and later use the data as you please, without a need to loop through your data.

Go through your file line by line and use the `.split()` method with the according delimiter to split the columns. Save the data of the lines, i.e. by appending to a `list` or by adding them to a `dictionary`. Afterwards, write your modified lines to a file.

To be more RAM efficient, you could handle all days separately (whenever a new data appears), provided your file is sorted by date.

Comment: If you have a solution with a loop, it would be appreciated as well. I am pretty stuck here.

Comment: So your question is how to calculate the "w1 = w0*(1+r0)/(sum(all w1 that day))" values? You can calculate temporary solutions, ignoring the denominator, and divide it later. There is no need to calculate the actual numerators and denominators in recursive manner, as the result will not ever change. Unless I misunderstand the variables.

Comment: Yes! in reality it is Wt = Wt-1(1+Rt-1)/sum of all wt that day

where t-1 is yesterdays value

So how do you mean temporary solution? That is what I am trying to achive but cant manage